# get a display object on stage/root?

Tags: actionscript-3

how can I get a display object on stage/root from a class?

the text field txt is in root, but how can I get it from a class?

```
var txt = new TextField();
with(txt){
    type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    border = true;
    textColor = 0xffffff;
    multiline = true;
    x = 20;
    y = 20;
    width = 270;
    height = 40;
}
addChild(txt);
txt.name = 'test';

class classTest {
    public function classTest{
        trace(this.getChildByName('test'));
    }
}
var cls = new classTest();
```

Comment: Are you implementing this code via the timeline or document class?

Comment: Trying to call getChildByName() will throw a compiler error because the classTest class doesn't have that method. classTest needs to subclass the Sprite or MovieClip class to inherit getChildByName().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your doing, but the simplest way would be to parse a reference to root or the DisplayObject object containing your Textfield object, and then access the TextField object via that reference within your ClassTest class.

```
var txt:TextField = new TextField();

with(txt)
{
     type = TextFieldType.INPUT;     
     border = true;
     textColor = 0xffffff;
     multiline = true;     
     x = 20;     
     y = 20;     
     width = 270;     
     height = 40; 
} 

addChild(txt); 
txt.name = 'test';  

class ClassTest 
{
     public function ClassTest(p_target:DisplayObjectContainer)
     {         
          trace(p_target.getChildByName("test"));  

     } // end function

}// end function

var classText:ClassText = new ClassTest(this); // parse a reference to root
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand you correct.
But, if you add a name to your display object you could try next code

```
txt.name = "txt_1";
this.getChildByName("txt_1");
```

**UPDATE**

better not to do like this. it's better to use events to communicate between classes, but anyway:

```
class classTest {
    private var _r : MovieClip; //not sure about the type
    public function classTest(r:MovieClip){
        _r = r;
        trace(_r.getChildByName('test'));
    }
}
var cls = new classTest(this);
```

Comment: ok.. but if the scope is a class this will be the class.. how can I refer to the stage/root scope?

Comment: if you are using code like addChild(txt); then you can use code like getChildByName("txt_1"); it will refers to children of the stage. try this.

Comment: how can I refer to the root from inside a class??

Comment: not the best option but working one: You can create a variable that refers to your root.. i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

(in a new class file)

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;

public class classTest extends Sprite
{
    public function classTest
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function added(evt:Event):void
    {
        trace(stage.getChildByName("test"));
    }
}
```

`Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` will enable you to reference the stage when it fires permitting you've instantiated the class and added it to the stage (which is why the event should fire in the first place).